# Using AccountManager to implement passwords

Tags: android, eclipse, passwords

I was wondering if someone knows how to use AccountManager in Android to implement passwords?

So what I have is a regular password input box that looks like this:

```
Enter password:
[password field]
[enter button]
```

And this is the change password boxes that I'm using.

```
Enter your current password:
[password field]
Enter your new password:
[password field]
[enter button]
```

What I'm having trouble with is making them work through AccountManager. Does anyone have a tutorial to do this? I'd really appreciate it.

*note* sorry I had to explain it like this, but I can't post pictures until I get 10 reps.

Comment: Try reading the API here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

SampleSync example is available in the samples provided by the android sdk.